Issue with Serving Asset Files via Docker and Nginx Proxy Pass
I am working on a project using Docker and Nginx. I am trying to serve asset files via Nginx on port 80 and proxy pass requests to port 8080. My goal is that when the project runs with Tomcat and a request to localhost:8080/assets-path is made, it serves the assets from the file path I have mounted in Docker. However, my configuration is not working as expected.
Below is my setup:
Dockerfile:
FROM nginx:1.21.6-alpine
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

default.conf:
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost.com;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
    
    location /so/ {
    }
    
    location /ol/ {
    }
    
    location /enw/ {
    }
    
    location /cofax {
    }
    
    location /ev/ {
    }
}

Docker Run command:
docker run -d --network=host -v assets-path:/usr/share/nginx/html:Z -p 80:80 httpd:local

The Problem:
I expect that when I hit localhost:8080/assets-path, the assets should be served from the mounted directory. However, this is not working as intended.
Am I missing something in my Nginx configuration, or is there another way I should approach this?
info: I'm using M2 Macbook Air.
I expected that when a request was made to localhost:8080/assets-path, Nginx would serve the static assets from the mounted directory, while proxying all other requests to Tomcat on port 8080.

Is the -v option literally exactly what you've shown?  With no slashes on the left-hand side of -v, it mounts a named volume and not a host directory.  COPYing the content into your image, or letting the backend serve its own static assets, might be easier to set up and more reliable.

Yes, it might be more reliable, but my main issue right now is that even though my files are served on port 80, the Tomcat server running on port 8080 can't access them, even though there's a proxy in place.

What URL are you calling, from where?  Does your Nginx configuration need to mention the /assets-path URL path?  (As it's written now, I'd expect that to forward to port 8080.)  (--network=host isn't usually a best practice, but you will need some other networking option to be able to reach another container, and it won't be localhost.)
